# ag-grid community css not work in angular

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I created an angular project angular version is 14 and I want to use the ag-grid table in my project when I install the ag-grid community in the project that's version is 30. when i start to implement in my project than CSS not work properly.

I add css file two-three different method
1 styles.css
2 angular.json file
3 index file

style.css

```
@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";
```

in angular.json

```
"node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
"node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css",
```

in html

```
 <ag-grid-angular style="width: 800px; height: 350px;" class="ag-theme-alpine" [rowData]="rowData"
                    [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
                </ag-grid-angular>
```

in component

```
  columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    { field: 'make' },
    { field: 'model' },
    { field: 'price' }
];

rowData = [
    { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxster', price: 72000 }
];
```

style.css

```
@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";
```

in angular.json

```
"node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
"node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css",
```

in html

```
 <ag-grid-angular style="width: 800px; height: 350px;" class="ag-theme-alpine" [rowData]="rowData"
                    [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
                </ag-grid-angular>
```

in component

```
  columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    { field: 'make' },
    { field: 'model' },
    { field: 'price' }
];

rowData = [
    { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxster', price: 72000 }
];
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

@import '~ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
@import '~ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-balham.css';

I also did this cdn but not work I try multiple; times but not got the results.
When I install ag-grid I used this command

npm install --save ag-grid-community ag-grid-angular

After a couple of hours, i used this command one by one
1 npm install --save ag-grid-community
2 npm install --save  ag-grid-angular

and import these files

@import '~ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
@import '~ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-balham.css';

and working fine.

thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

Your styles.css have typos, that's why you see this:

[image: Wrong]

Please change this

```
@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";
```

into this

```
@import '~ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
@import '~ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-balham.css';
```

Forked project: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/ag-grid-angular-example-forked-pd5d2z?file=%2Fsrc%2Fstyles.css%3A5%2C11

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time please read my below answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. you can try to enter the `package.json` file and modify the version of `ag-grid` (for my case I had Angular 14 and ag-grid 30) and I modified the version of `ag-grid` to the version:

```
    "@angular/router ": "^14.2.0",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^27.2.1",
    "ag-grid-community": "^27.3.0"
```

And for file css:

```
    @import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css";
    @import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css";
```

And in file app.module.ts:

```
    import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';
```

```
in **imports** you add :
```

```
AgGridModule.withComponents([])
```